# Using Linux Bash Script to get data from XML file

Tags: xml, linux

I have a XML files with data in it that I need to extract with a Linux Bash Script. For example, I need everything in the  brackets and  to print out in terminal accordingly (first name in next to first description).

What is the best way to do this? I was able to do it with c# using XPath, but I can't do that simply using a Linux Bash Script correct? I know I can get most of it done with awk, sed, grep, cut ect, but I don't think (actually I know I am not) doing it properly. I am at a point were I extracted description data to a file and name to a file, but after a few hours, I realized this is not the best/proper way.

Example of how it should read is.

- name1 - description1
- name2 - description2
- name3 - (blank)
- name4 - description3

Thank you!

If I can add any detail to make it clearer, please let me know! (Brain is a little fried from a long day at work)

Sample XML (simplified it down to one instance)

```
<zabbix_export>
<templates>
    <template>
        <items>
            <item>
                <name>Available memory</name>
                <description>Available memory is defined as free+cached+buffers memory.</description>                  
            </item>
        </items>
    </template>
<templates>
```

How it should read out:

```
<name>Available memory</name> - <description>Available memory is defined as free+cached+buffers memory.</description>
<name>Another Name</name> - <description>Another Description</description>
<name>Another Name</name> - <description>Another Description</description>
<name>Another Name</name> - <description>Another Description</description>
```

Comment: Sample XML data would be useful

Comment: Added a simplified example of the XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch an `xpath` command from bash.  It installs with Perl XML and allows you to do any XPath queries to stdout very comfortably.

Comment: Well, I have been trying to get it to work in Perl doing it that way, but I can't seem to get it to work (never used Perl before). I know it is possible to get it to print like this just using Bash Script.

Comment: I really only want to use Linux Bash Script commands (not Perl or anything)

Comment: @PolarisUser - and you really get right that.  `xpath` is a command line utility that you run directly from Bash.  You only need to know in which package to find it in case that it is not pre-installed on your system which would be a surprise for me.

Comment: Okay, well I am at the point where I have all the data using XPath with Perl, but I can't seem to format it properly, like I posted :(

Comment: @PolarisUser - You can follow this previous question (answer) and come back if you run in any other trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629091/format-and-combine-output-of-xpath-in-bash

Answer (score 3):

#### command

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//item/*' -c . -n input.xml |
    sed '2~2s/$/\n/' |
        awk -F'\n' -vRS='' '{print $1" - "$2}'
```

#### output

```
<name>Available memory</name> - <description>Available memory is defined as free+cached+buffers memory.</description>
<name>Available memory</name> - <description>Available memory is defined as free+cached+buffers memory.</description>
<name>Available memory</name> - <description>Available memory is defined as free+cached+buffers memory.</description>
```

Comment: So, almost there!!! I got that to work properly, but some of my descriptions in my XML file are blank. Is there a way for it to skip the blank descriptions so it displays properly?

Answer (score 0):

If the `xpath` executable is not installed, you can install it like so:

```
cpan XML::XPath
```

That should download the necessary Perl module, and install the `xpath` binary.