# Get xmllint to output xpath results \n-separated, for attribute selector

Tags: xml, parsing, shell

How can I get xmllint to output multiple results of xpath selector for attributes "per line"?

Take this example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <config>
          <tagX key1="value1 " key2=" value2"/>
          <tagY key3="value3" key4=" value4 "/>
  </config>


  $ xmllint example.xml --xpath "/config/*/@*"
```

The result is:

```
   key1="value1 " key2=" value2" key3="value3" key4=" value4 "
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
   key1="value1 "
   key2=" value2"
   key3="value3"
   key4=" value4 "
```

Would I need to split after even-numbered quote marks, or is there any neater way to do this?

There's a related question, [about the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629091/format-and-combine-output-of-xpath-in-bash) except it's about picking out contents of `<tag>value</tag>`, and not `<tag attribute="value" />`

Comment: Does this help -- `echo 'cat /config/*/@*[starts-with(name(),"key")]' | xmllint --shell input.xml`

Comment: @devnull: `| grep =` and it's fine. (actually, no `[starts-with()...` just `/@*` I used "key1, key2..." as metasyntactic variables, the actual attribute names would be arbitrary.)

Comment: Yes, `grep -v` and done!

Comment: @devnull: I'd prefer inclusive grep (all desired lines contain `=`, and undesired are rather fixed: `/ > cat /config/*/@*` and ` -------` - and it's possible the value might contain `-------`, so `grep '='` is sure to find what I want (unless I use `=` in the selector, which I don't.)

Comment: @devnull: By the way, post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Value only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823736/with-xmllint-xpath-parse-out-the-value-of-several-attributes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try:

```
$ xmllint --shell inputfile <<< 'cat /config/*/@*'
```

You might need to `grep` the output, though, so as to filter the undesired lines.

Comment: Agree with Guss.  Also I could work around parsing the diagnostics and the separator lines (with a different XPATH expression in my case), `xmllint --shell /tmp/tt.xml <<< "cat //s/text()" | { read -r diag; while { read -r separator; read -r line; } ; do echo "${line}" ; done ; } > /tmp/tt-words.txt`

Answer (score 6):

If it's an option, try using xmlstarlet instead:

`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/config/*/@*" example.xml`

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but as I came to this post searching a solution to the same problem, here is my solution

On linux add sed substitution to split output:

```
$ xmllint example.xml --xpath "/config/*/@*" | sed "s| key|\nkey|g"
```

of course the substitution expression depends on your xml structure and your xpath query.

And you can even add line numbers on each line if you add nl

```
$ xmllint example.xml --xpath "/config/*/@*" | sed "s| key|\nkey|g" | nl
```

Which gives

```
   1 key1="value1 "
   2 key2=" value2"
   3 key3="value3"
   4 key4=" value4 "
```

Comment: The problem of this is that it depends on consistent naming scheme of the keys (properties). If they are not 'key1, key2' but 'name, birthdate', this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If using the latest xmllint, results should have been separated by `\n` now. However, if fields contain `\n`, you can use this [patched](https://gitlab.gnome.org/cykerway/libxml2/commit/6c7a378117ad7c5300b99161b4a7ce4e2df61bc6) version to use `\0` as a separator, with `--xpath0`. For whatever reason the [PR](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/merge_requests/8) hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: the commit link is dead

Comment: @kbolino [moved](https://gitlab.gnome.org/cykerway/libxml2/commit/6c7a378117ad7c5300b99161b4a7ce4e2df61bc6)

Answer (score 1):

I found that Ubuntu v.14 and v.18 use too old libxml2 versions.
So i solved the issue mentioned in the topic by the recompiling of libxml2 v2.9.10.

1) Download the sources of libxml2 from http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/libxml2.html

2) Download the test suite:

```
$ wget http://www.w3.org/XML/Test/xmlts20130923.tar.gz
```

3) Execute:

```
$ tar xf libxml2-2.9.10.tar.gz
```

4) Execute:

```
$ cd libxml2-2.9.10/
```

5) Execute:

```
$ sed -i 's/test.test/#&/' python/tests/tstLastError.py
```

6) Execute:

```
$ export CPATH="/usr/include/python3.6/:$CPATH"
```

7) Execute:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y python3-libxml2 python3-pip
```

8) Execute:

```
$ sudo pip3 install libxml2dom
```

9) Execute:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static --with-history --with-python=/usr/bin/python3 && make
```

Ensure here that the returning code ($?) is 0.

10) Execute:

```
$ tar xf ../xmlts20130923.tar.gz
```

11) Execute:

```
make check > check.log
```

Ensure here that the returning code ($?) is 0.

12) Execute:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Enjoy

```
$ xmllint data.xml -xpath "//some_child/ancestor::some_parent/attribute::id"                                                                               
 id="1"
 id="10010"
 id="10011"
 id="10020"
 id="10021"
```