# How to append a newline after every match using xmlint --xpath

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, xmllint

I have the following HTML code:

```
<textarea name="command" class="setting-input   fixed-width" rows="9">1</textarea><textarea name="command" class="setting-input   fixed-width" rows="5">2</textarea>
```

I would like to parse it to receive such output:

```
1
2
```

Currently I am using:

```
xmllint --xpath '//textarea[@name="command"]/text()' --html
```

but it does not append a newline after each match.

Comment: How are you getting the output now? and where did you test it?

Comment: @Babai Assuming the above HTML code is available in file f, `xmllint --xpath '//textarea[@name="command"]/text()' --html f`

Comment: Actually I did test it in online tool,and the text are coming in a new line.. so trying to understand where you want to print it..

Comment: @Babai In that case, I guess the tool you are using behaves differently than `xmllint`.

Comment: Hello from the future! This behavior was fixed in libxml2 version 2.9.9, and `--xpath` now (finally) does the thing you expect when dumping XPath nodes. If you are stuck with an old libxml2, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48311523/785213) below for an alternative solution using XMLStarlet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hello from the year 2020!

As of v2.9.9 of libxml, this behavior [has been fixed in `xmllint` itself](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/commit/da35eeae5b92b88d8ebdb64b4b327ac1c2cf1bce).

```bash
echo \
'<textarea name="command" class="setting-input fixed-width"
 rows="9">1</textarea>
<textarea name="command" class="setting-input fixed-width"
 rows="5">2</textarea>' \
  | xmllint --xpath '//textarea[@name="command"]/text()' --html -

# result:
# 1
# 2
```

However, if you're using anything older than that, and don't want to build libxml from source just to get the fixed `xmllint`, you'll need one of the other workarounds here. As of this writing, the latest CentOS 8, for example, is still using a version of libxml (2.9.7) that behaves the way the OP describes.

As I gather from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971965/785213), it's theoretically possible to feed a command into the `--shell` option of older (<2.9.9) versions of `xmllint`, and this will produce each node on a separate line. However, you end up having to post-process it with `sed` or `grep` to remove the visual detritus of shell mode's (human-oriented) output. It's not ideal.

---

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), if available, offers another solution, but you do need to use `xmlstarlet fo` to format your HTML fragment into valid XML before using `xmlstarlet sel` to extract nodes:

```bash
echo \
'<textarea name="command" class="setting-input fixed-width"
 rows="9">1</textarea>
<textarea name="command" class="setting-input fixed-width"
 rows="5">2</textarea>' \
  | xmlstarlet fo -H -R \
  | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v '//textarea[@name="command"]' -n
```

If the `Attempt to load network entity` message from the second `xmlstarlet` invocation annoys you, just add `2>/dev/null` at the very end to suppress it (at the risk of suppressing other messages printed to standard error).

The XMLStarlet options explained (see also the [user's guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/)):

- `fo -H -R` — **fo**rmat the output, expecting HTML input, and recovering as much bad input as possible

  - this will add an `<html>` root node, making the fragment in the OP's example valid XML
- `sel -T -t -v //xpath -n` — **sel**ect nodes based on XPath `//xpath`

  - output plain text (`-T`) instead of XML
  - using the given template (`-t`) that returns the value (`-v`) of the node rather than the node itself (allowing you to forgo using `text()` in the XPath expression)
  - finally, add a newline (`-n`)

**Edit(s)**: Removed half-implemented `xmllint --shell` solution because it was just bad. Added an XMLStarlet example that actually works with the OP's data.

Comment: The link provided points at the accepted answer on this page.

Comment: Ha. Good catch. Something else must've been in my clipboard. Fixed now. `:)`

Comment: If you're parsing someone else's HTML, it's also worth noting that "well-formed" (X)HTML of the variety that `xmllint` and `xmlstartlet` can parse without errors seems to be ... a rarity these days. You could try `xmllint --html` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21480073/785213), which is slightly more forgiving of the input format. Sometimes even _that_ doesn't work, and I'll take the input HTML one pass through [`tidy`](http://www.html-tidy.org/) first. Or give up and use a regex, at which point I've got _two_ problems.

Comment: Is it broken again in v2.9.10 ? I have `xmllint: using libxml version 20910` and I'm not getting newlines.

Comment: @malhal With the OP's test data, I get the newlines as expected using both 2.9.10 in Debian Bullseye and 2.9.13 from MacPorts. The code modifications to add the newlines [are still in there](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/blame/2.10/xmllint.c?no_pagination=true#L2062), so it's difficult to surmise what might be happening on your end without more information.

Answer (score 5):

Try [this patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/cykerway/libxml2/commit/6c7a378117ad7c5300b99161b4a7ce4e2df61bc6), which provides 2 options:

- `--xpath`: same as old `--xpath`, with nodes separated by `\n`.
- `--xpath0`: same as old `--xpath`, with nodes separated by `\0`.

Test input (`a.html`):

```
<textarea name="command" class="setting-input   fixed-width" rows="9">1</textarea><textarea name="command" class="setting-input   fixed-width" rows="5">2</textarea>
```

Test command 1:

```
# xmllint --xpath '//textarea[@name="command"]/text()' --html a.html
```

Test output 1:

```
 1
 2
```

Test command 2:

```
# xmllint --xpath0 '//textarea[@name="command"]/text()' --html a.html | xargs -0 -n1
```

Test output 2:

```
 1
 2
```

Comment: it would be great to have this feature merged

Comment: @AdamSiemion Not sure if they have rw access to their gnome git repo. If they host their source on github I'd be happy to send a pull request. Plus, need someone from their team to do some sanity check.

Comment: @Cyker Your [merge request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/merge_requests/8) is just languishing there, still open, but your `--xpath` fixes to add a newline [were basically implemented](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/commit/da35eeae5b92b88d8ebdb64b4b327ac1c2cf1bce) for v2.9.9. So thanks!

Comment: @TheDudeAbides Thanks for the reminder. That change hardcoded `\n` in strings, which makes separating with `\0` almost impossible. So this patch can no longer be merged and I won't rebase. I'll just leave it there in case someone doesn't need the latest features but `\0`.

Comment: @Cyker Bummer. Your efforts are appreciated, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following, ugly trick, please feel free to provide a better solution.

Changed the HTML code by replacing `</textarea>` with `\n</textarea>` using the following command:

```
sed 's/\<\/textarea/\'$'\n\<\\/textarea/g' f
```

Comment: You can use other characters as separators for sed, e.g. `%`, so you don't need to escape the slash.

Comment: If ugly, don't post it at all. 'sed' is not a XML parser

Answer (score 0):

Below is a wrapper script intended exactly to the purpose of newlines delimited output (for old releases of `xmllint`).

Create a file `xmllint2.sh` with the contents. Then execute `chmod u+x xmllint2.sh`, finally run like:

`./xmllint2.sh --xpath --html '//textarea[@name="command"]/text()' 2>/dev/null`

(the last part of the command is to hide the output of warnings that occurs with html)

```
#!/bin/bash

# wrapper script to
# - have newline delimited output on Xpath querys
# - implements --xpath on very old releases

/usr/bin/xmllint --xpath &>/dev/null
implements_xpath=$?

newlines_delimited_xmllint_version=20909
current_version=$(xmllint --version |& awk 'NR==1{print $NF;exit}')

args=( "$@" )
if [[ $@ == *--xpath* ]]; then
    # iterate over positional parameters
    for ((i=0; i<${#args}; i++)); do
        if [[ ${args[i]} == --xpath ]]; then
            xpath="${args[i+1]}"
            unset args[i+1]
            unset args[i]
            break
        fi
    done
    if [[ ($implements_xpath==0 && $current_version>=20909) || $file == - || $file == /dev/stdin || $xpath == / || $xpath == string\(* ]]
    then
        exec /usr/bin/xmllint "$@"
    else
        exec /usr/bin/xmllint "${args[@]}" --shell <<< "cat $xpath" | sed '1d;$d;s/^ ------- *$//;/^$/d'
    fi
else
    exec /usr/bin/xmllint "$@"
fi
```

Check latest revision: https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint

Debian Buster in June 29 2020 have version 2.9.4 which is 4 years old.
Debian testing/experimental have 2.9.10, which is the fixed version.

Another way to install 2.9.10 with Debian last stable: https://serverfault.com/a/1022826/120473 (without taking the risk of crashing the `apt` system)

Comment: I tried 20910 and it doesn't appear to have the newline fix but I edited your script to remove the version check and was able to carry on with what I'm doing.

Comment: I may be missing something, @Gilles-Quenot, but I can't see how `$file` is assigned. Will those checks always be missed?

Answer (score 0):

Newlines can legitimately appear in xml data. A more robust approach would be to delimit xpath results by a character that is guaranteed to not occur in XML data. The [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), U+0000 in the [Universal Coded Character Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set), is one such character.

> Note that the code point U+0000, assigned to the null control
> character, is the only character encoded in Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646
> that is always invalid in any XML 1.0 and 1.1 document.
> – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML

@Cyker's [merge request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/merge_requests/8) for `xmllint` included the addition of an `-xpath0` option that would delimit xpath results by NUL. [A new feature request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/issues/227) for this functionality was opened as well.

Hopefully, `xmllint` will gain this feature soon.

### xmlstarlet

In the mean time, another xpath command line tool, `xmlstarlet`, can be coaxed into achieving this goal now. `xmlstarlet` does not currently support output of NULs directly, but we can make it output `U+FFFF`, which, like NUL, is guaranteed to not occur in XML data ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets)). We then just need to translate `U+FFFF` to `U+0000` and we'll have NUL delimited xpath results.

In the following examples, I'll use the following partial html file. It's the same example from the OP's question, except I added newlines for testing purposes.

```
cat >data.html <<'EOF'
<textarea name="command" class="setting-input fixed-width" rows="9">1 
 newline</textarea>
<textarea name="command" class="setting-input fixed-width" rows="5">2 
 newline</textarea>
EOF
```

Here is how to use `xmlstarlet` and `sed` to delimit the xpath results with NULs:

```
xmlstarlet fo -H -R data.html \
| xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//textarea[@name="command"]' -v '.' -o $'\uffff' \
| sed s/$'\uFFFF'/\\x00/g
```

<sup>`perl` could be used instead of `sed`, if you prefer: `perl -CS -0xFFFF -l0 -pe ''`</sup>

Note: I ran the HTML through `xmlstarlet fo -H -R` as shown in @TheDudeAbides answer.

Now that the xpath results are delimited by NULs, we can process the results with the help of `xargs -0`. Example:

```
xmlstarlet fo -H -R data.html \
| xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//textarea[@name="command"]' -v '.' -o $'\uffff' \
| sed s/$'\uFFFF'/\\x00/g \
| xargs -0 -n 1 printf '%q\n'
```

Result:

```
'1 '$'\n'' newline'
'2 '$'\n'' newline'
```

or load it into a bash array:

```
mapfile -t -d '' a < <(
 xmlstarlet fo -H -R data.html \
 | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//textarea[@name="command"]' -v '.' -o $'\uffff' \
 | sed s/$'\uFFFF'/\\x00/g
)

declare -p a
```

Result:

```
declare -a a=([0]=$'1 \n newline' [1]=$'2 \n newline')
```

### saxon

Same technique using saxon instead of xmlstarlet:

```bash
xmllint --html data.html --dropdtd --xmlout \
| java -cp "$CP" net.sf.saxon.Query -s:- -qs:'//textarea[@name="command"]' !method=text !item-separator=$'\uFFFF' \
| sed s/$'\uFFFF'/\\x00/g \
| xargs -0 -n 1 printf '%q\n'
```