# Using xmllint and xpath with a less-than-perfect HTML document?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xmllint

I have an HTML page that is generated by an existing tool - I cannot change the output of this tool.

However, I want to use `xmllint` with the `--xpath` option to pick out a few specific pieces of information from the downloaded webpage. The problem is that the page starts with:

`<html lang=en><head>...`

And `xmllint` throws errors nearly immediately:

```
html.out:2: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected
<html lang=en><head>
           ^
```

The issue certainly seems to be the missing enclosing quotation marks around the value of the `lang` attribute. The entire page is full of this kind of issue. (Though only sporadically.)

Nearly every browser can parse this just fine - how can I convince `xmllint` to do so as well? I would like to avoid having to inject an intermediate step to "fix" the file. Instead, I would like to either:

1) Find a flag, validation option, etc. that helps the parser along, or:

2) Use some other tool. (But what? `xmllint` is always my go-to for command line XPath commands.)

Further, using just `xpath` results in:

```
> xpath html.out '//myquery...'

not well-formed (invalid token) at line 2, column 11, ...
```

Comment: XML is not HTML and viceversa. Beware!

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo This is definitely true! I'm reminded of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/88111 However, in this case I'm just looking for a one-liner that will *work*, not one that will stand the test of time and make my future children proud.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can enable the HTML parser in `xmllint` using the `--html` command line option. That way, you will be able to process HTML documents.

Comment: This does work online in few cases. I wasn't able to find any other switching for making `xmllint` ignore non-standard HTML files, like browser.

Answer (score 9):

If does not abort the parsing, you can just hide the errors with:

```
2>/dev/null
```

Then there is  [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), which I made just for picking some data from  html pages. (although it is not perfect. I was told about two malformed documents it could not handle)

```
xidel  html.out -e //yourquery...
```

Answer (score 6):

You should pre-process the HTML with a lenient parser. (That's the main difference: HTML is allowed a much more lax syntax than XML.) That is, try [HTML5-Tidy](http://w3c.github.io/tidy-html5/) and let XMLLint work on the result:

```
input HTML
 |
 v
Tidy
 |
 v
xmllint
 |
 v
result
```

Comment: would `xmlstarlet` work as well as `xmllint` for parsing the file `tidy` creates?

Comment: In principle, Tidy's result should be well-formed XML, so you can throw it at any XML processing tool chain with the expectation to Just Work™.