# How to parse out the value of several attributes on different elements with xmllint/xpath?

Tags: xml, bash, xpath

For a given xml file called *configurations.xml* I would like to extract the *value* of each `conf` element, and store it in a variable for later use.

```
<configurations>
  <conf name="bob"/>
  <conf name="alice"/>
  <conf name="ted"/>
  <conf name="carol"/>
</configurations>
```

The expected output is:

```
bob
ailce
ted
carol
```

I have *xpath* and *xmllint* available. A xpath of `//conf/@name` gets the nodes, but outputs as `name="bob"`, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve what you're trying to achieve with `xmllint` only.

Since you have `xpath` installed, you have Perl's `XML::XPath` too. So a little bit of Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Path;

my $xp=XML::XPath->new(filename => 'configurations.xml');

my $nodeset=$xp->find('//conf/@name');
foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    print $node->getNodeValue,"\0";
}
```

will output what you want, separated with a nil character.

In a one-liner style:

```
perl -mXML::XPath -e 'foreach $n (XML::XPath->new(filename => "configurations.xml")->find("//conf/\@name")->get_nodelist) { print $n->getNodeValue,"\0"; }'
```

To retrieve them in, e.g., a Bash array:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' n; do
    names+=( "$n" )
done < <(
    perl -mXML::XPath -e 'foreach $n (XML::XPath->new(filename => "configurations.xml")->find("//conf/\@name")->get_nodelist) { print $n->getNodeValue,"\0" }'
)
# See what's in your array:
display -p names
```

Note that at this point you have the option of turning to Perl and drop Bash completely to solve your problem.

Comment: I was mostly considering if it was possible in pure bash. But I guess it doesn't make sense in the end.

Answer (score 3):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//configurations/conf' -v '@name' -n a.xml
```

worked since `xmllint` does not seem capable. Good intro [here](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2005/11/linux-20051115/2/).

Tested on: xmlstarlet version 1.5.0, Ubuntu 14.04.

It fails however on large files: `ulimit -Sv 500000` (limit it to 500Mb) dies on a 1.2Gb XML, and jams my computer without the memory limit. See also:

- [How to validate large XML (>100MB) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528249/tools-to-validate-large-xml-100mb-file)
- [xmlstarlet sel on large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653844/xmlstarlet-sel-on-large-file)

Answer (score 0):

I searched everywhere for this seemingly simple answer. It appears that it is not possible for `xmllint` to print attribute values from multiple nodes. You can use `string(//conf/@name)`, but that will only print a single value even if there are multiple nodes that match.

If you are stuck with `xmllint`, the only way is to use additional text processing. Here's a generic way that will parse out the attribute value. It assumes the values do not contain `=` or `"` characters.

```
xmllint --xpath //conf/@name | 
tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F= '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g'
```

The first pipe converts spaces to newlines.

The second pipe prints what's after the `=`

The last pipe removes all `"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `awk` command to make it done.

```
[root@myserver tmp]# cat /tmp/test.xml
<configurations>
  <conf name="bob"/>
  <conf name="alice"/>
  <conf name="ted"/>
  <conf name="carol"/>
</configurations>
[root@myserver tmp]# awk -F \" '{print $2}' /tmp/test.xml |grep -v '^$'
bob
alice
ted
carol
[root@myserver tmp]#
```

Comment: I need it to be a more specific match, than just everything starting with ". There'll be other elements in the XML document that I don't want to match.

Comment: So you want only `conf name` in that case ?

Answer (score -1):

If you *really* want use `xpath` *and* to display only the attribute values without the "name=" part, then here's what worked for me:

```
xpath configurations.xml 'string(//conf/@name)' 2>/dev/null
```

In plain English, wrap your XPath query in `string()`, and also suppress the verbose ouput of `xpath` by adding `2>/dev/null` at the end.

Comment: This does not work for me on libxml version 20901 Ubuntu 14.04: it only prints the first value when using `string()`

Comment: You are right, I only tested with a single child node. I'll leave the answer untouched, maybe it can be useful for 0.1% of the people having this problem.