# Get value of an attribute from xml for multiple occurrences using xmllint

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix, xmllint

I want to get value of conn of abc whose name is 3 i.e conn3

```
<abc name="1">
    <properties conn="conn1"/>
</abc>
<abc name="2">
    <properties conn="conn2"/>
</abc>
<abc name="3">
    <properties conn="conn3"/>
</abc>
```

currently i am doing

```
echo 'cat //abc/properties/@conn' | xmllint --shell "test.xml"
```

but it is returning conn1,conn2,conn3

I am trying with

```
echo 'cat //abc[@name='1']/properties/@conn' | xmllint --shell "test.xml"
```

but it is not returning anything

Can you please suggest where i am doing wrong. 
`Note:Xpath` not supported

Comment: Given that XML (and wrapping it in a `<root>` element to make it valid), your second command works for me. I guess what you have is something different?

Comment: Works for me, too.  Although if you don't have the `--xpath` option, I wonder if your `xmllint` is old and doesn't support the particular query you're using...

Comment: Printing  "/ > / >" to the console

Comment: What is the expected output, exactly? Related for siblings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823736/how-to-parse-out-the-value-of-several-attributes-on-different-elements-with-xmll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally issue was with single inverted comma(') below command worked for me. I don't know the reason, came to know by hit and try :)

Please comment if you know the reason behind it.

```
echo 'cat //abc[@name="1"]/properties/@conn' | xmllint --shell "test.xml"
```

Note: Above mentioned XML is only sample actual XML where I want to run is complex structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `xmllint` normally, without pipes:

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'string(//abc[@name='1']/properties/@conn)' xml_file
conn1
```

See `string()` is used to get the value of an attribute, as described in [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532084/1983854).

Comment: Hi, --xpath not supported :(

Comment: What does your `xmllint --version` return? Mine `xmllint: using libxml version 20901`.

Comment: xmllint: using libxml version 20706
I am using linux box xmllint --xpath
Unknown option --xpath
Usage : xmllint [options] XMLfiles .