# I cant figure out a way to write a xpath for fetching Edit Tests/Remove Tests elemets for a specific row

Tags: xpath

Listing a sample of structure:

```
    <tbody class="">
                <tr class="">
                    <td class=""><img src="http://dummyurl1.jpg" class=""></td>
                    <td class="">Test</td>
                    <td class="">Test-0000001</td>
                    <td class="">
                        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEditDialog" class="btn btn-primary" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-546="546">
                            Edit Tests
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-547="547">
                            Remove Tests
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-548="548">Print Test</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="">
                    <td class=""><img src="http://dummyurl.jpg" class=""></td>
                    <td class="">Testing</td>
                    <td class="">Test-0000002</td>
                    <td class="">
                        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEditDialog" class="btn btn-primary" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-549="549">
                            Edit Tests
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-550="550">
                            Remove Tests
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-551="551">Print Test</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here I do have the Test Id's as Test-000000X. However, I tried and could not isolate the elements at row level.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Here I do have the Test Id's as Test-000000X. However, I tried and could not isolate the elements at row level."*

How about :

```
//tr[td='Test-000000X']
```

The above should return the row where one of the column content equals 'Test-000000X'.

Answer (score 0):

For single access use

```
//tr[1]/td[3]/text()
//tr[2]/td[3]/text()
```

Example

```
[~] 
$ xmllint --xpath "//tr[1]/td[3]/text()"  yourXmlFile.xml 
Test-0000001

[~] 
$ xmllint --xpath "//tr[2]/td[3]/text()"  yourXmlFile.xml
Test-0000002
```

For automatically iterating over all occurrences use

```
   //tr/td[3]/text()
```

Example with xmllint

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//tr/td[3]/text()"  yourXmlFile.xml
```

Gives

```
Test-0000001Test-0000002
```

Example with newlines in between [(using this trick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965071/get-xmllint-to-output-xpath-results-n-separated-for-attribute-selector)

```
xmllint --shell yourXmlFile.xml <<< 'cat //tr/td[3]/text()'
```

gives

```
/ >  -------
Test-0000001
 -------
Test-0000002
```

With yourXmlFile.xml

```
<tbody class="">
            <tr class="">
                <td class=""><img src="http://dummyurl1.jpg" class=""/></td>
                <td class="">Test</td>
                <td class="">Test-0000001</td>
                <td class="">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEditDialog" class="btn btn-primary" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-546="546">
                        Edit Tests
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-547="547">
                        Remove Tests
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-548="548">Print Test</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td class=""><img src="http://dummyurl.jpg" class=""/></td>
                <td class="">Testing</td>
                <td class="">Test-0000002</td>
                <td class="">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEditDialog" class="btn btn-primary" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-549="549">
                        Edit Tests
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-550="550">
                        Remove Tests
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-551="551">Print Test</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is to isolate the elements at every row. This way I will again get Test-000000 and Test-0000002. Whereas I just need one at a time.

Comment: Using of xmllint is just an example. In other contexts you will get a list of isolated matches, e.g. in Java a NodeList or similar. So the xpath itself should do what you have asked for. I will add some trick on how to separate the strings in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below `XPath`:

```
//td[text()="Test-0000001"]/following-sibling::td/button[.="Edit Tests"]
```

for `Test-0000001` `Edit Tests` button and

```
//td[text()="Test-0000001"]/following-sibling::td/button[.="Remove Tests"]
```

for `Test-0000001` `Remove Tests` button

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for the response. I have never used following-sibling syntax before but it works like a charm. Even making the xpath relative is quite easier with this. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You can mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your issue